# VBA unloads userform very slowly

Tags: vba, userform

I developed some Excel VBA tool on my laptop and it runs rather smoothly. When I tried to run it on a different machine now, I realized that everything works fine but the Unload Me task when closing userforms takes "ages" (about 4-5 seconds of Window's spinning wheel), even if no calculations are made, e.g. by clicking on "cancel". The CPU monitor shows a high spike during these periods, however. The code I use is all but extraordinary, it's as simple as

```
Private Sub Cancel_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

The computer I'm using the tool on now does not have a slower CPU, if at all it's probably even more powerful so that's probably not the reason. Same goes for RAM. I tried `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` but it doesn't help either. However, my own one runs Office 2019 while this one only has 2013. Not sure if Microsoft implemented (way) faster routines for this in between? Or do you have other ideas about how else I could speed up the process? Thanks in advance!

PS: If I add a break point at "End Sub" and then press F5/F8, the alogrithm is instantaneous just as it should be (?!).

Comment: Are you using late binding to create your form?

Comment: The userform is created by simple 
`Sub AddAlternative_Click()
    Form_AddAlternative.Show
End Sub`

Comment: That's a tricky question. Have you already tried to just unload your userform?

Comment: I just tried it and unfortunately it takes the same time.

Comment: My guess would be that releasing resources that you create or open during the form's lifetime takes time. Easiest way of finding out is triage. Take a good look at what the form does. Comment out the bits that look most suspiciously like they could be responsible, see at which point timings normalize.

Comment: @Tomalak this would have been my guess, too. However, the form only contains a few textboxes, three radiobuttons and three empty comboboxes. So there's no data that's generated whatsoever. So I can't really make it do less than it already does. :D

Comment: Of course you can. Comment out *everything*. Any changes?

Comment: ...or create a new, completely empty form. If that closes instantly and your form doesn't, it's likely something you did in your form.

Comment: Well, that's true of course. I created a new, empty form but the issue persists.

Comment: Okay next thing to check - is it something with your Excel? What happens if you create VBA forms in Word?

Comment: One place to look are Add-ins. Another thing worth checking is program activity with [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). With luck you get a lead out of that

Comment: Both in Word as well as in a new Excel test file, the unloading works smoothly. So indeed it seems to be an issue related to my document. One of my forms actually unloads perfectly well but so far I haven't been able to spot the difference of this particular form compared to the others. Unfortunately, I cannot run Process Monitor as I'm trying to run it on my office computer which is subject to strict IT security guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the issue. It was not the unloading itself, it was a piece of my code that is executed on detours after closing the userform. When I coded the tool, it still ran quicker but now I know where to start optimizing. Thanks to all of your for your help!